# Angular2 http get result empty for custom post types wordpress toolset

Tags: wordpress, angular

I am using wordpress rest api and angular2 to build simple one page app. I created a custom post type with toolset. All is working fine and I can see the data returning fine.

http://tncorp.biffapps.com/wp-json/wp/v2/downloads/?filter[product]=Pico

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSQVG.jpg)

When try to request the data in my Angular application, the response body is empty.

Response
_body
:
"[]"
headers
:
Headers
ok
:
true
status
:
200
statusText

Does anyone know why this is happing?

Code for the http get:

```
getProductDownloads($id): Observable<any> {

    this.ProductsDownloads = this.http.get(this.wpurl + 'downloads/?filter[product]='+$id)
        .map(res => {
            console.log('GET DOWNLOAD',res)
            return this.ProductsDownloads = this.extractData(res)
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);

    return this.ProductsDownloads;
}
```

Comment: Your api example returns an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return the Observable itself:

```
getProductDownloads($id): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.wpurl + 'downloads/?filter[product]='+$id)
    .map(res => {
        console.log('GET DOWNLOAD',res)
        return this.ProductsDownloads = this.extractData(res)
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Then when you're calling it, you *subscribe* to the Observable.

```
// I'm using "this" here, but if you have it in a -service- you'd put that there
this.getProductDownloads(id).subscribe(result => {
   this.products = result;
});
```

Also, you could do it the following way and incorporate the `| async` pipe in your template instead of manually subscribing & unsubscribing.

```
this.products = this.getProductDownloads(id);

// template:
{{ products | async }}
```